# Random positioned icons in a div with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to create a `div` in which to position multiple material design icons at random positions.

**For Example like this:**

[image: collection of icons]

This is something I made using jQuery, but now I want to make this in VueJS, and not with shapes but with multiple material design icons.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('.main').append('<div class="box"></div>');
}
$( '.box' ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).css({
    left : Math.random() * ($('.main').width() - $(this).width()),
    top : Math.random() * ($('.main').height() - $(this).height())
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  /* parent width - box width */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A solution using a [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) within a [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)-generated project:**

We can use Vue's [list rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) to recreate your `for`-loop. We add [template refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on `.main` and `.box` to get element references for the calculations below:

```html
<template>
  <div ref="main" class="main">
    <div ref="box" class="box" v-for="i in 10"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

From the element references, we use [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) to calculate the box dimensions upon [mounting](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted):

```html
<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    // wait for $refs to be available
    await this.$nextTick()

    this.$refs.box.forEach(box => {
      box.style.left = Math.random() * (this.$refs.main.clientWidth - box.clientWidth) + 'px'
      box.style.top = Math.random() * (this.$refs.main.clientHeight - box.clientHeight) + 'px'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

The original CSS can be copied into a `<style>` block:

```html
<style>
.main {
  /* insert original .main styles here */
}

.box {
  /* insert original .box styles here */
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/creating-a-component-in-vue-v570h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/RandomDots.vue)

You could use the same steps above with SVG paths to load random Material Design icons. For instance, [bind a `<path>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to a random SVG path from [`@mdi/js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mdi/js) (a popular MDI library):

1. Create a data property (named `"icons"`), and initialize it with a random range of icons from `@mdi/js`:

   ```js
   import * as mdiIcons from '@mdi/js'

   function randomInt(min, max) {
     min = Math.ceil(min)
     max = Math.floor(max)
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
   }

   function randomIcons(count) {
     const allIcons = Object.values(mdiIcons)
     const start = randomInt(0, allIcons.length - count)
     return allIcons.slice(start, start + count)
   }

   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         icons: randomIcons(10),
       }
     },
   }
   ```
2. Replace the `<div ref="box">` from the earlier example with `<svg ref="box">`. And inside the `<svg>`, add `<path :d="icons[i]" />`, which binds to the random icons we generated above.

   ```html
   <template>
     <div ref="main" class="main">
       <svg ref="box" class="box" v-for="i in 10">
         <path :d="icons[i]">/>
       </svg>
     </div>
   </template>
   ```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/random-material-design-icons-rrbq2?file=/src/components/RandomIcons.vue)